# Proving that a particular function is measurable

Tags: integration, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel measurable function. Define
$$g(y) = \begin{cases} \frac{\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x,y) dx}{\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) dx} & \text{if } \displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) dx >0,\\ \\0 & \text{if } \displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) dx =0.\end{cases}$$ Can we say that $g$ is also measurable?

I know that if $f(x,y)$ is measurable $y \mapsto \displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) dx $ is measurable, but what can be said about $y \mapsto \displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x,y) dx $ ?

Comment: If $g(x,y)$ is measurable then $\int_{\mathbb R} g(x,y)f(x,y)\ \mathsf dx$ is measurable, as the product of measurable functions is measurable. Here $g(x,y)=x$.